# Retrieving specific table items from sqlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite database that I am trying to query in order to find all the items of a specific type. Here is the function that I am calling in order to query my database:

```
Cursor c = dbi.DBGrabTable("LEGS",ExerciseListActivity.this);
```

Here is the function definition:

```
 public Cursor DBGrabTable(String type, Context ctx){

    String query="SELECT * FROM " + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_EXERCISES + " WHERE Type=" + type;
    DBContract.DBHelper mDBHelper = new DBContract.DBHelper(ctx);
    SQLiteDatabase rdb = mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor  c = rdb.rawQuery(query,null);

    if (c != null)
        return c;
    else
        return null;
}
```

The error that I am getting is as follows:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: LEGS (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Exercises WHERE Type=LEGS

Therefore I am thinking it has something to do with the SQL query. I am unsure why it is saying "no such column: LEGS" I am trying to query my database to look in my Table named "Exercises" under the column header "Type" and select all the items that have the word LEGS in that column.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? A huge thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Check the table definition whether the column and table name available.

2 - If table and column is available and type is text please change your sql query and try it.

```
String query="SELECT * FROM " + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_EXERCISES + " WHERE Type=" + "'" + type + "'";
```

Comment: Damn, you're good! All I needed was the single quotes around type.

Comment: I know, its common for me another hint to add TABLE(DOT)COLUMNNAME, whenever you join query with multiple table. This is also common mistake which I used to do...

Answer (score 0):

Use this query and make sure in maintenace of space and inverted comma. Check your Column name(Type) in TABLE_EXERCISES.

```
"SELECT * FROM " + DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_EXERCISES + " WHERE Type = '" + columnValue + "'";
```

move the cursor till last row of table.

```
if (cursor != null) {
     if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         do {

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```